# OnClickListener for the ImageView in side CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-view, android-toolbar

I've got an `ImageView` inside of a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and I'd like to attach a `View.OnClickListerner` to it. However a click doesn't seem to trigger the listener.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/view_nade_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/view_nade_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_nade_collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/view_nade_backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/view_nade_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/view_nade_fab"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_24dp"
    app:fab_colorNormal="?android:attr/colorAccent"
    app:fab_colorPressed="?android:attr/colorAccent"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/view_nade_appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the Activity:

```
@BindView(R.id.view_nade_backdrop) ImageView mBackdrop;
@BindView(R.id.view_nade_appbar) AppBarLayout mAppbar;
@BindView(R.id.view_nade_collapsing_toolbar) CollapsingToolbarLayout mCollapsingToolbar;
@BindView(R.id.view_nade_toolbar) Toolbar mToolbar;

private final View.OnClickListener mOnBackdropClickListener = (v) ->
{
    final Intent intent = new Intent(ViewNadeActivity.this, GalleryActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(GalleryActivity.EXTRA_PHOTO_URIS, ListUtils.join(mUtilityData.getImgUris(this)));
    startActivity(intent);
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_nade);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    mBackdrop.setOnClickListener(mOnBackdropClickListener);
}
```

EDIT:
Here is the `OnTouchListener` that I attach to the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` (credit: [@azizbekian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1083957/azizbekian))

```
private final View.OnTouchListener mOnToolbarTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
    {
        int action = motionEvent.getActionMasked();
        if(mBackdropBounds != null && (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL))
        {
            if(mBackdropBounds.contains((int) motionEvent.getRawX(), (int) motionEvent.getRawY()))
            {
                if(mBackdrop != null)
                {
                    mBackdrop.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. The `Toolbar`'s height was set to `wrap_content` which made it extend across the whole `AppBarLayout` when expanded and consume all touch events. For anyone that comes along, you have 2 solutions. You can either do what @azizbekian proposed, but register the listener to the `Toolbar` and not the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` or change the `Toolbar`'s `layout_height` property to a fixed value (ex. `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`), but in that case it won't trigger the click on top of the `ImageView` where the `Toolbar` actually is.

Answer (score 4):

If you turn on `show layout bounds`, you'd see, that there's a layout on top of your `ImageView` that actually won't let your click event to reach to the `ImageView`.

What I ended up with was:

1. wait until `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is once fully expanded
2. Once it is expanded you can get the `Rect` of your `ImageView` (this `Rect` contains coordinates of the view in the view hierarchy)
3. Once you have that rectangle, you should listen for touch events in `CollapsingToolbarLayout`
4. if that touch event's x,y position is within the `Rect` that you saved in previous step, then you should intercept that touch event and delegate that `MotionEvent` to `ImageView`.

As an implementation you can see [this](https://github.com/azizbekian/Spyur/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/azizbekian/spyur/mvp/listing/ListingPresenter.java#L70) project. `mMapLogoRect` is the `Rect` of the `ImageView` within `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

Comment: For some reason the `OnTouchListener` never fires on the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. I updated the anwser with full xml code.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try these two things:

1.Remove these two things from CollapsingToolbarLayout:

```
app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
```

2. And put this in Toolbar :

   ```
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
   ```

Do it like this: First test with 1, then with 2, then with both. 
Also make sure, you set ImageView's height to a bigger value, like 200dp. If any criteria make it work, let me know. I will then edit it accordingly.